# Como formatar date php, para exibir 'Hojé as 00:00' e 'Ontem as 00:00'?

Tags: php, mysql, data

Tenho um registro no banco de dados TIMESTAMP e queria exibir por exemplo:

- Se a data é atual, mostrar: 'Hoje às 00:00'
- Se estiver a data de ontem no banco, exibir 'Ontem às 00:00'
- E se for mais de 1 dia atrás, exibir o dia normalmente, '08/06/2017 às 00:00'

```php
$topico_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');  
$exibir = date('d/m/Y H:i:s', strtotime($topico_date);//Exibe: 08/06/2017 17:00:15
```

Como a data é de hoje queria que exibisse: Hoje às 17:00

Comment: Olá, poderia compartilhar por favor 3 exemplos. Também o código do timestamp e o que deveria ficar como um "de -> para"?

Comment: Geralmente isso é feito por JavaScript – porque o PHP processaria a informação uma vez só, mas o tempo continua andando a partir daí.

Comment: Editei o post, olha ai

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Existe algumas formas de lidar com essa situação. Vou expor aqui uma forma simples:

```
<?php
    function converterData($data){
        $dInicio = new DateTime($data);
        $dFim  = new DateTime();
        $dDiff = $dInicio->diff($dFim);
        $dias = $dDiff->days;

        if($dias <= 0) {
            return 'Hoje às ' . $dInicio->format('H:i');
        } else if($dias == 1) {
            return 'Ontem às ' . $dInicio->format('H:i');
        }

        return $dInicio->format('d/m/Y') . ' às ' . $dInicio->format('H:i');
    }

    $topico_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); // Será armazenado 2017-06-08 17:12:32 por exemplo
    echo converterData($topico_date); // Irá imprimir Hoje às 17:12
?>
```

Utilizando a função converterData, você irá obter o valor desejado.

Vale ressaltar que para o código acima funcionar você deve ter uma versão do **PHP5** maior ou igual a 5.3.0 ou a versão **PHP7**.

Referência: [PHP: DateTime::diff - Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php)

Comment: você pode usar apenas um `if` e `else`, o terceiro `return não precisa estar dentro de uma condição. :)

Answer (score -1):

Você pode capturar a diferença entre os dias e verificar se é `>1`, `1` ou `0`, sendo:

`> 1`: dias que se passaram (diferença)

`1:` Um dia de diferença (ontem)

`0:` Hoje

```
$today = new DateTime('2017-06-08'); // Com timestamp a hora sera incluida
$days = new DateTime('2017-06-08');

$interval = $today->diff($days)->format('%a');
$hour = $today->diff($days)->format('%H:%i:%s');


echo $interval == 0 ? "Hoje às {$hour}" : 
    ($interval == 1 ? "Ontem às {$hour}" : 
    "{$interval} dias atrás");

//Resultado: Hoje às...
```

Comment: segue teste: http://ideone.com/0freXr